# How to make differently named movies in a for-loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Say i have a for-loop.

```
count=1;
for t=1:20

    while(true)
        figure();
       (do sth...)
       view([-90 -90])
       pause(0.01)
       M(count)=getframe;
       count=count+1;
     end

movie2avi(M, 're.avi');
end
```

Inside the for-loop there is a while loop where i am making my movie. But in each iteration of for loop one movie is made. I want to store each movie with name as re1, re2,...re20,etc. How to do modify the command `movie2avi(M, 're.avi');` to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the index `t` to a string using [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) and concatenate:

```
movie2avi(M, ['re',num2str(t),'.avi']);
```

This will generate `re1.avi`,`re2.avi`,...,`re20.avi`.

---

For better sorting of the files, you may want to add a leading `0` to the filenames as well:

```
movie2avi(M, ['re',num2str(t,'%02G'),'.avi']);
```

This will generate `re01.avi`,`re02.avi`,...,`re20.avi`. The extra argument `'%02G'` is a [formatspec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#inputarg_formatSpec) that creates an integer-looking string of at least length 2 with zeros padding numbers of length 1.